How to dynamically select Bash command based on dag_run.conf for a manually triggered DAG in Apache Airflow
I'm trying to create a manually triggered DAG in Apache Airflow that can run different ETL processes based on a specified action in dag_run.conf. The idea is to define several ETLs as bash commands and select one dynamically when the DAG is triggered.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime

ETL_PROCESS_1 = " ".join(
    """
    /opt/bin/python /opt/scripts/process_1.py
    -d "{{ dag_run.conf.get('data', '') }}"
    -p "{{ dag_run.conf.get('parameters', '') }}"
    -e "{{ dag_run.conf.get('end_date', '') }}"
    -s "{{ dag_run.conf.get('start_date', '') }}"
    """.split()
)

ETL_PROCESS_2 = " ".join(
    """
    /opt/bin/python /opt/scripts/process_2.py
    --filters "{{ dag_run.conf.get('filters', '') }}"
    """.split()
)

ETL_PROCESS_3 = " ".join(
    """
    /opt/bin/python /opt/scripts/process_3.py
    --kpis "{{ dag_run.conf.get('kpis', '') }}"
    """.split()
)

ETL_ACTIONS = {
    "process_1": ETL_PROCESS_1,
    "process_2": ETL_PROCESS_2,
    "process_3": ETL_PROCESS_3,
}

SELECTED_COMMAND = "{{ ETL_ACTIONS[dag_run.conf['action']] }}"

default_args = {
    "owner": "user",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "email_on_failure": True,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "retries": 0,
}

with DAG(
    "manual_trigger_dag",
    max_active_runs=1,
    default_args=default_args,
    description="Manual Trigger for ETL Processes",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2024, 9, 5),
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    task = BashOperator(
        task_id="execute_etl",
        bash_command=SELECTED_COMMAND,
    )


When I try to use SELECTED_COMMAND as the bash_command in my BashOperator, I get an error because ETL_ACTIONS isn't available when rendering the Jinja template. Direct templating works with simpler variables, but I need the flexibility to pick from multiple ETL commands on demand.
How can I dynamically set bash_command based on dag_run.conf['action']? Is there a way to handle this logic within the BashOperator, or should I look at another approach?
Thanks in advance!
